# How to get specific data from block of data based on condition

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
[group]
enable = 0
name =  green
test = more

[group]
name  = blue
test = home

[group]
value = 48
name = orange
test = out
```

There may be one ore more space/tabs between label and `=` and value.
Number of lines may wary in every block.
I like to have the `name`, only if this is not true `enable = 0`

So output should be:

```
blue
orange
```

Here is what I have managed to create:

```
awk -v RS="group" '!/enable = 0/ {sub(/.*name[[:blank:]]+=[[:blank:]]+/,x);print $1}'
blue
orange
```

There are several fault with this:

1. I am not able to set `RS` to `[group]`, both this fails `RS="[group]"` and `RS="\[group\]"`.  This will then fail if `name` or other labels contains `group`.
2. I do prefer not to use `RS` with multiple characters, since this is `gnu awk` only.

Anyone have other suggestion? `sed` or `awk` and not use a long chain of commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that groups are always separated by empty lines, set `RS` to the empty string:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '!/enable = 0/ {sub(/.*name[[:blank:]]+=[[:blank:]]+/,x);print $1}'
blue
orange
```

---

@devnull explained in his answer that GNU awk also accepts regular expressions in `RS`, so you could only split at `[group]` if it is on its own line:

```
gawk -v RS='(^|\n)[[]group]($|\n)' '!/enable = 0/ {sub(/.*name[[:blank:]]+=[[:blank:]]+/,x);print $1}'
```

This makes sure we're not splitting at evil names like

```
[group]
enable = 0
name =  [group]
name = evil
test = more
```

Comment: Good idea, I did forget about the blank line `RS`

Comment: Both solutions avoid the first record entirely.

Comment: That's because of the `'NR>1` I copied from the question without thinking about...

Comment: @Steve that is OK, I do have some info lines at top needed to be removed, so If you gave him one minus, for this, you could remove it.  Also change my post to remove the `NR>1` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Accepted this answer, since it was the first to post `RS=""`. It fixed both the problem in one go.  No need to have the `[[]` and its compatible with most `awk`

Answer (score 5):

Your problem seems to be:

> I am not able to set RS to `[group]`, both this fails `RS="[group]"` and
>   `RS="\[group\]"`.

Saying:

```
RS="[[]group[]]"
```

should yield the desired result.

Comment: What `awk` implementation are you using that uses more than the first characters of `RS`? Try `RS="[[]foo[]]"` on the data given above to see what I'm writing about...

Comment: Thanks this works, but why does not escape work?  @JensErat: only `gnu awk` supports multiple characters in `RS` variable.

Comment: Good to know, but then I'd also make sure `[group]` is on its own line – see my updates answer...

Answer (score 5):

In these situations where there's clearly `name = value` statements within a record, I like to first populate an array with those mappings, e.g.:

```
map["<name>"] = <value>
```

and then just use the names to reference the values I want. In this case:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '
{
    delete map
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,tmp,/ *= */)
        map[tmp[1]] = tmp[2]
    }
}
map["enable"] !~ /^0$/ {
    print map["name"]
}
' file
blue
orange
```

If your version of awk doesn't support deleting a whole array then change `delete map` to `split("",map)`.

Compared to using REs and/or sub()s., etc., it makes the solution much more robust and extensible in case you want to compare and/or print the values of other fields in future.

Comment: I need some time to understand why we needed to delete the array, but now I do see that if there are value in some field for one block and not in another block, it will use the old value and give wrong data.

Comment: Even if I accepted other answer, I ended up using this solution.  Its give me much better control of the data.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have line-separated records, you should consider putting `awk` in paragraph mode. If you must test for the `[group]` identifier, simply add code to handle that. Here's some example code that should fulfill your requirements. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    RS=""
}

{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=3) {

        if ($i == "enable" && $(i+2) == 0) {

            f = 1
        }

        if ($i == "name") {

            r = $(i+2)
        }
    }
}

!(f) && r {

    print r
}

{
    f = 0
    r = ""
}
```

Results:

```
blue
orange
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\[group\]/{:a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba};/enable\s*=\s*0/!s/.*name\s*=\s*\(\S\+\).*/\1/p;d}' file
```

Read the `[group]` block into the pattern space then substitute out the colour if the `enable` variable is not set to `0`.

- `sed -n '...'` set sed to run in silent mode, no ouput unless specified i.e. a `p` or `P` command
- `/\[group\]/{...}` when we have a line which contains `[group]` do what is found inside the curly braces.
- `:a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba}` to do a loop we need a place to loop to, `:a` is the place to loop to. `$` is the end of file address and `$!` means *not* the end of file, so `$!{...}` means do what is found inside the curly braces when it is not the end of file. `N` means append a newline and the next line to the current line and `/\n$/ba` when we have a line that ends with an empty line branch (`b`) to `a`. So this collects all lines from  a line that contains `[group] to an empty line (or end of file).
- `/enable\s*=\s*0/!s/.*name\s*=\s*\(\S\+\).*/\1/p` if the lines collected contain `enable = 0` then do not substitute out the colour. Or to put it another way, if the lines collected so far *do not* contain `enable = 0` *do* substitute out the colour.

Comment: +1. I am the fun of `sed`, when see someone resolved the problem with sed, I will vote it up.

Comment: It works, but I have bug trouble understanding this `sed`. Can you give an explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the record separator, you could use a dummy variable like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function endgroup() {
   if (e == 1) {
      print n
   }
}

$1 == "name" {
   n = $3
}

$1 == "enable" && $3 == 0 {
  e = 0;
}
$0 == "[group]" {
   endgroup();
   e = 1;
}

END {
   endgroup();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use Bash for this.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "enable = 0" ]]; then
        n=1
    else
        n=0
    fi
    if [ $n -eq 0 ] && [[ $line =~ name[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]([a-z]+) ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi
done < file
```

This will only work however if `enable = 0` is always only one line above the line with `name`.